# Increase in third party libraries

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, lighthouse

Lately, I was working on the speed optimization of our website, by following suggestions from the lighthouse. On the 9nth of October, our performance fell down drastically, and it was hard to find the reason because we didn't merge any changes to the master, not that day, nor 3 days before. The only thing I found is that number of the third-party libraries increased from 27 to 37, which means that we are downloading some additional data and probably more scripts are being executed.

Here is the list of new libraries has been added:

```
1) Weborama
2) The trade desk
3) Smart AdServer
4) Pubmatic
5) mbr targeting
6) IS Group
7) Improve Digital
8) Dataxu
9) AppNexus
10) Adscale
11) Adobe Tag Manager
```

I was able to find them only in the calibre app, by going to third party libraries tab, like in the image below.

[image: calibre app thrid party libraries]

but the problem is that there is only the name of third party libraries, and nothing else, I couldn't find them in the network tab.

Any suggestions on how I can find where these libraries coming from? The way we include scripts in our application is only by google tag manager or directly. There were no changes there, and I even checked the npm packages, and we didn't install anything so far.

Comment: looks like whatever advertising platform you are using? Care to share a URL so we can help identify the source of them?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie yeah, thanks. https://paulcamper.de/

Comment: hey @GrahamRitchie, is there any way I can contact you privately?